# Azure AD B2C as SAML IdP - RelayState Too Big

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We're trying to use AWS Cognito user pool as SP and Azure AD B2C as IdP per [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/connect-with-saml-service-providers). Unfortunately, we haven't had any success yet. The SAML request is failing. The SAML response from Azure B2C has the following status message, indicating the RelayState content from AWS Cognito is too big (> 1000 byte max):

```
<samlp:Status>
      <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Requester" />
      <samlp:StatusMessage>The SAML RelayState content is greater the 1000 bytes.</samlp:StatusMessage>
      <IsPolicySpecificError>false</IsPolicySpecificError>
</samlp:Status>
```

After decoding the RelayState (2x base64), we see this (some sensitive names changed to abc's):

```
{"userPoolId":"us-east-1_Vu6ccYQri","providerName":"ABCD-B2C-TEST","clientId":"s1ldupjg52rk4vrrumab75nq0","redirectURI":"abcdefghij://abcdefghij.abc.com/authmain","responseType":"code","providerType":"SAML","scopes":["aws.cognito.signin.user.admin","email","openid","phone","profile"],"state":null,"codeChallenge":null,"codeChallengeMethod":null,"nonce":"DDKMFvrQXZl1ML2Fg9pPTRVamRmx06_nWNSNV5wDsFp6-Nl4OcM2FixoNg5FHoIJ7LlT4tByiSE7-2NqeFhLhx_n7y-m_e6BQnBYFWwYdQr7LUMUj9HJDMLds1rkxP4ttwXPFMv4Yq5gpRnSkoW0jeZ1hkMIvqGZyNo8X82PZkA","serverHostPort":"abcdefghijklmnopqrs.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com","creationTimeSeconds":1583530949,"session":null,"userAttributes":null,"isStateForLinkingSession":false}
```

We tried to shrink the size with everything we can control, but the smallest we could get is still too big after encoding it. The cryptographic nonce is the biggest part, but we can't control that.

We also tried tweaking the RequestContextMaximumLengthInBytes in the RP file, so far to no avail.

Any suggestions on how to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved by increasing the RequestContextMaximumLengthInBytes in the Relying Party (RP) file. Although a value of 2000 still resulted in failure, 4000 was large enough to make the error go away.

```
<Metadata>
  <Item Key="RequestContextMaximumLengthInBytes">4000</Item>
</Metadata>
```